# TabHost in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Hello Friends I implement TAbHost in my code and I want to tab below any widgets(Button, TextView, etc..)but I am not do this. Plz Help me.

Means in Xml at Top widgets and below widgets tab will be presented.

Comment: I found my Andswer..... Thankx for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting to put tabs at top or tabs at bottom of Layout? i couldn't understand.

If you mean at the top I suggest you do the [Google Tab Layout Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
         android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />
<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```